# How to make a save workspace functionality in jointjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jointjs, rappid

I am new to JointJS. My need to use JointJS library is to have a module in my project that a user can make flowcharts in his dashboard panel. I have implemented [this](http://resources.jointjs.com/demos/kitchensink) example in my project. I want an option to save the workspace in this example. Please suggest if it is possible and how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: its possibile but hard, you will need to map all your elements and their position then save them in a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`graph.toJSON` / `graph.fromJSON` might help you out. Docs: https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.1/joint.html#dia.Graph.prototype.toJSON

Comment: Great. I have done it with the help of your code hint. Thanks.